# Set a limit on the amount of numbers that can be entered into a "masked textbox"

Tags: c#, integer, mask, maxlength, maskedtextbox

I am still learning the basics with C# and i am having some trouble. I have been searching the internet for about 3 hours now for an answer on how to set a limit on the amount of characters(in this case it will be limited to a 3 digit integer) a user can enter into a "masked Textbox". I have come across a few different kinds of code, but when i run the program i am still able to enter in as many characters i want. If there is no argument i can add on to do this (meaning i will have to set a loop to check every time) please let me know. I am struggling to learn. Here is the small piece of code that i am attempting to work on.

```
private void mtbMales_MouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mtbMales.Text = "";
    mtbMales.SelectionStart = 0;
    mtbMales.MaxLength = 3;
    mtbMales.Mask = "000";
}
private void mtbFemales_MouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    mtbFemales.Text = "";
    mtbFemales.SelectionStart = 0;
    mtbFemales.MaxLength=3;
    mtbFemales.Mask = "000";
}
```

Comment: Is this WPF or Windows Forms?

Comment: Windows forms, sorry i shouldve stated that first.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `MaxLength` property on the textbox?

Comment: not a textbox, its a masked textbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the Mask Property of the masked text box to OOO in the design mode, and you're done.

[image]

If you want to set it programmically, set it in the form load event (Double click the form in Design mode)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mtbMales.MaxLength = 3;
        mtbMales.Mask = "000";
    }
```

Comment: conanak99 thanks man it worker like a charm. I would up the vote but i apparently need 15 rep to do so :-(

Comment: The MaxLength only sets the length of the text, we have to use the mask to make sure the input is interger.